# Is it possible to suppress Bindings.select null warning?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm displaying a `ListView` which might or might not have a selected item.

On its side there's a panel showing the selected items' sub-properties (the panel's visibility is bound to `selected.isNonNull()` so it won't show if the list view has no selected item). I'm doing this with `Bindings.select()`.

The problem is that if there's no selection, the syserr get's flooded with null warnings. Is there a way to suppress them?

Comment: No. This is really annoying. A bug was posted about this a long time ago and the idiot who wrote that code refused to fix it (even though the API docs for `Bindings.select` explicitly support the case where intermediate values are null). Consider using something like [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) which includes a [much richer bindings API](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html) that is compatible with the properties and bindings in the standard API.

Comment: And no changes about this in JavaFX 9?

Comment: The original bug report is here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096919. The linked bug is still unassigned and unfixed. I haven't tried it in Java 9 but I don't think it's fixed. The ReactFX API is way superior in other ways too (e.g. it's typesafe and the properties are compile-time checked), if you can use a third party library here.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. You're always the best on javafx :)

Comment: The real credit belongs to Tomas, who wrote the alternative API.

Comment: I did note from the mailing list comments (linked from the bug report above), that the messages are being piped via the logger. So if you use a logging API there should be some way to suppress those "warnings" ("Warning: your code is working exactly as expected") via the logging configuration.

Comment: @James_D tssse ... thought all those were fixed along with https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094059 ...

Comment: @kleopatra I still see warnings with Java 9 (just testing quickly). AFAIK, the value returned in the case where an intermediate value is null is still returned from a catch block, and since this is behavior that is explicitly documented in the API, using exceptions to process that logic is not really acceptable (as we all learned in elementary school...).

Comment: @James_D Did you mean EasyBind? Can't find anything similar to my problem in ReactFx (which I already started using for some other feature).

Comment: @MouseEvent The functionality from EasyBind is incorporated into ReactFX 2.0 (different class names, but same functionality). See http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html

Comment: @James_D yeah, you are right, unfortunately :( But good idea to disable the logging altogether -         `Logger.getLogger("javafx.beans").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);` or OFF - we don't want to see any logging from core in application code, ever.